# HBase exception

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera

When I use HBase in pseudo cluster mode, I am getting the below exception. It will be really great if somebody could shed some light on this issue to resolve it

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=10, exceptions:
Wed Feb 06 15:22:23 IST 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable@29422384, java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Could not iterate StoreFileScanner[HFileScanner for reader reader=file:/home/688697/hbase/test/c28d92322c97364af59b09d4f4b4a95f/cf/c5de203afb5647c0b90c6c18d58319e9, compression=none, cacheConf=CacheConfig:enabled [cacheDataOnRead=true] [cacheDataOnWrite=false] [cacheIndexesOnWrite=false] [cacheBloomsOnWrite=false] [cacheEvictOnClose=false] [cacheCompressed=false], firstKey=0deptempname0/cf:email/1360143938898/Put, lastKey=4191151deptempname4191151/cf:place/1360143938898/Put, avgKeyLen=45, avgValueLen=7, entries=17860666, length=1093021429, cur=10275517deptempname10275517/cf:place/1360143938898/Put/vlen=4]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.next(StoreFileScanner.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.KeyValueHeap.next(KeyValueHeap.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreScanner.next(StoreScanner.java:289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.KeyValueHeap.next(KeyValueHeap.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion$RegionScannerImpl.nextInternal(HRegion.java:3004)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion$RegionScannerImpl.next(HRegion.java:2951)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion$RegionScannerImpl.next(HRegion.java:2968)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.next(HRegionServer.java:2155)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1345)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumException: Checksum error: file:/home/688697/hbase/test/c28d92322c97364af59b09d4f4b4a95f/cf/c5de203afb5647c0b90c6c18d58319e9 at 37837312 exp: -819174049 got: 1765448374
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.verifySums(FSInputChecker.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.readChecksumChunk(FSInputChecker.java:276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.fill(FSInputChecker.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read1(FSInputChecker.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read(FSInputChecker.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.readFully(FSInputChecker.java:431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.seek(FSInputChecker.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.seek(FSDataInputStream.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$FSDataBoundedInputStream.seek(ChecksumFileSystem.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$AbstractFSReader.readAtOffset(HFileBlock.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$FSReaderV2.readBlockData(HFileBlock.java:1318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2.readBlock(HFileReaderV2.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2$ScannerV2.readNextDataBlock(HFileReaderV2.java:452)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2$ScannerV2.next(HFileReaderV2.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.next(StoreFileScanner.java:99)
    ... 12 more

Wed Feb 06 15:22:24 IST 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable@29422384, java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.convertThrowableToIOE(HRegionServer.java:1079)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.convertThrowableToIOE(HRegionServer.java:1068)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.next(HRegionServer.java:2182)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1345)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2$ScannerV2.next(HFileReaderV2.java:395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.next(StoreFileScanner.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.KeyValueHeap.next(KeyValueHeap.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreScanner.next(StoreScanner.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.KeyValueHeap.next(KeyValueHeap.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion$RegionScannerImpl.nextInternal(HRegion.java:3004)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion$RegionScannerImpl.next(HRegion.java:2951)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion$RegionScannerImpl.next(HRegion.java:2968)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.next(HRegionServer.java:2155)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: When exactly does this exception occur? When scanning a table? When bulk loading data into a table?

Comment: @Pieterjan - I was doing an export from HBase table to MySQL. The size of data stored into HBase is 1 GB.

Comment: seems like the data files are corrupted because of some mysterious  file system ops. Did you make any change for the Cloudera data mount poit?

Comment: Please share your hostfile entry. and regionserverfile entries

Comment: and alos verify if your namenode is in safe mode

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this issue resides in your /etc/hosts file. If you check your /etc/hosts file you will find a entry something like the one below (in my case mu machine is named domainnameyouwanttogive)

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 domainnameyouwanttogive
```

The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts

```
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

The root cause is that domainnameyouwanttogive resolves to 127.0.1.1 which is incorrect as it should resolve to 127.0.0.1 (or a external IP). As my external IP is 192.168.58.10 I created the following /etc/hosts configuration;

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.43.3 domainnameyouwanttogive
```

The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts

```
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

This will ensure that the resolving of your host processes on your localhost will be done correctly and you can start your HBase installation correctly on your development system.

And also please make sure that  your hadoop namenode is running with same domain name you are using for hbase